# How to decode dictionary JSON response in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

```
struct Chat: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id =  UUID()
    var Messages: [Messages]
}


class ChatApi : ObservableObject{
    @Published var chats = Chat()
    
    func loadData(completion:@escaping (Chat) -> ()) {
        let urlString = prefixUrl+"/room"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        request.setValue(accessKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Access-Key-Id")
        request.setValue(secretkey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Access-Key-Secret")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let chats = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Chat.self, from: data!)
            print(chats)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(chats)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

I'm not able to decode the following JSON response using Swift.

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

I have tried the above ways and Xcode keeps throwing error. Although I'm able to decode JSON response with another function that are like this

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

I'm able to decode JSON response that are returned as arrays but not as dictionaries.

Example response to decode

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "_id": "MS4mMbTXok8g",
            "_created_at": "2022-04-05T10:58:54Z",
            "_created_by": {
                "_id": "Us123",
                "Name": "John Doe",
            },
            "_modified_at": "2022-04-05T10:58:54Z",
            "Type": "Message",
            "_raw_content": "ss",
            "RoomId": "Ro1234",
        },
        {
            "_id": "MS4m3oYXadUV",
            "_created_at": "2022-04-04T15:22:21Z",
            "_created_by": {
                "_id": "Us678",
                "Name": "Jim Lane",
            },
            "_modified_at": "2022-04-04T15:22:21Z",
            "Type": "Message",
            "_raw_content": "ss",
            "RoomId": "Ro1234",
        }
    ]
}
```

The data model that I've used is

```
struct CreatedBy: Codable {
    var _id: String
    var Name: String
}    
struct Messages: Codable {
    var _id: String
    var _created_by: CreatedBy?
    var `Type`: String?
    var _raw_content: String
}

struct Chat: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id =  UUID()
    var Messages: [Messages]
}
```

The error message before compilation is `Editor placeholder in source file`

Comment: Please show your datamodel, error message, and sample JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added datamodel and error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to introduce you to a couple of sites that will help when handling JSON decoding: JSON Formatter & Validator and Quicktype. The first makes sure that the JSON that you are working off of is actually valid, and will format it into a human readable form. The second will write that actual decodable structs. These are not perfect, and you may want to edit them, but they will get the job done while you are learning.

As soon as you posted your data model, I could see the problem. One of your variables is:

```
var `Type`: String?
```

The compiler is seeing the ` and thinking it is supposed to be a placeholder. You can't use them in the code.

Also, though there is not any code posted, I am not sure you need to make `Chat` `Identifiable`, as opposed to `Messages` which could be, but are not. I would switch, or at least add, `Identifiable` to `Messages`. I also made `CreatedBy` `Identifiable` since it also has a unique `id`.

The other thing you are missing which will make your code more readable is a `CodingKeys` enum. This translates the keys from what you are getting in JSON to what you want your variables to actually be. I ran your JSON through the above sites, and this is what came up with:

```
// MARK: - Chat
struct Chat: Codable {
    let messages: [Message]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case messages = "Messages"
    }
}

// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let createdAt: Date
    let createdBy: CreatedBy
    let modifiedAt: Date
    let type, rawContent, roomID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case createdAt = "_created_at"
        case createdBy = "_created_by"
        case modifiedAt = "_modified_at"
        case type = "Type"
        case rawContent = "_raw_content"
        case roomID = "RoomId"
    }
}

// MARK: - CreatedBy
struct CreatedBy: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

This gives you conventional Swift variables, as opposed to the snake case the JSON is giving you. Try this in your code and let us know if you have any more problems.

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors. After trying out the schema that you proposed, I'm getting an "Editor placeholder in source file". Another error is with the ChatApi Observable object, if I use this `@Published var chats = Chat()`, it says "missing argument for parameter "message" in call

Comment: You had the "Editor placeholder in source file" in your original code as well. You never said what line was causing the error. `@Published var chats = Chat()` doesn't make a ton of sense, either. A `Chat` is one chat with a bunch of messages, not multiple chats. Further, the reason you are getting that error is you are never doing anything to actually initialize `Chat`. I suspect you are calling `loadData()` in your view which means the that the line should either be `@Published var chats: [Chat] = []` if the API returns multiple chats. If it returns 1 chat, you may want to make it optional.

Comment: I’ll rewrite the file regarding the placeholder error and let you know. As for the API, it returns a single chat with only the “Messages” key which is an array.

Comment: I have resolved the above error but now in the ChatView.swift, `.onAppear() { ChatApi().loadData { (chats) in self.chats = chats}}.navigationTitle("Chat List")`,  I get an error saying --> Cannot assign value of type 'Chat' to type "['Chat']"